# Python: Subprocess.call fails to paste files into one

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I have some issues with subprocess that I can't figure out without throw any error messages

```
subprocess.call("paste T_1.csv T_2.csv T_3.csv > T.csv", shell=True)
```

T_1, T_2 and T_3 all exist and are not empty, but the T.csv is built but turns out to be an empty file.

Python is 3.9 and OS is win10.

Any help with this will be great!

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not have `paste`, this is not `subprocess` issue
And after Python3.5, it is better to use `run` instead of `call`

```
import subprocess

cmd = "copy /b T_1.csv+T_2.csv+T_3.csv T.csv"
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
```